# Finding if substring is in string recursivly

Tags: c, recursion

My goal is to call a function and the function will return me 0 / 1 if the sent string has the
sent substring in it , I do not need to find its index
for example:

String : "Hello World" 
SubString : "rl"
will return 1

String : "asssbdsd"
SubString : "ab"
will return 0

so I've come up with this solution :

```
int HasSubstr(char* mainStr, char* subStr)
{
    if (!*subStr)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (!*mainStr)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (*mainStr == *subStr)
    {
        return HasSubStr(mainStr + 1, subStr + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        while(*(subStr -1))
        {
            subStr--;
        }
        return HasSubStr(mainStr + 1, subStr);
    }
}
```

**but it's not a pure recursion and i need it to be a pure recursion
, help would be much applied**

Yes this is homework

Comment: This is homework, isn't it?

Comment: @Philipp: What else could it be? The Homework tag has been deprecated, so it is correctly tagged.

Comment: `it's not a pure recursion` why so? What is pure recursion?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck although the homework tag is deprecated, people should still mention in their question when it is homework, so that those who answer try to lead them to the solution in a way that they learn something from it instead of presenting a finished solution.

Comment: Aside comment: I think you would do better by passing some start index for `subStr` instead of "rolling" it back to the initial value. And, really, what is "a pure recursion"?

Comment: a pure recursion by my understanding is to not take control of the process , that you are given the calculation's on one step before and all you have to do is add the last calculation, for example:
to count amount of char's in a string one step before is them amount of char's before your step , and the step that you need to add is if the current char in the string equals the char to count

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to fit it all within one function.

```
int StartsWith(const char *mainstr,const char *subStr)
{
  if (*subStr == '\0') return 1;
  if (*mainStr != *subStr) return 0;
  return StartsWith(mainStr+1,subStr+1);
}

int HasSubstr(const char *mainStr,const char *subStr)
{
  if (StartsWith(mainStr,subStr)) return 1;
  if (*mainStr == '\0') return 0;
  return HasSubstr(mainStr+1,subStr);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ` if (*subStr == '\0') return 1;` in StartsWith?